# run ios app in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I'm new to iOS programming, I've managed to create a countdown timer that counts down to 0 and when the timer reaches 0 an UIAlertView pops up to say that the timer is done.

Although my problem is when I minimize the app or if the screen goes to sleep my countdown timers stops and my alert won't show up until I start the app again and let it count down to 0.

So my question is basically, how do I let the app run in the background, or at least let it count down in the background?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way will be to create a "local notification". When your app enters the background, cancel your timer, but schedule a local notification that will fire at the `fireDate` corresponding to when your timer hits "0". If the local notification fires while your app is in the background, the user will be presented with an appropriate alert and will have a chance to launch your app.

See the Apple [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) for instructions on how to schedule and then handle a local notification.